# delete all files except some in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am in need of a small script that cleans all files and directories except a few from a two levels down in a certain directory (module).

I am trying to get the following piece of TCL code to work:

```
proc add_module {module} {
    # Clean up old source IP-catalogs
    set clean_list [glob -nocomplain ${repo_dir}/src/pl/${module}/semi_top/*/*]
    set clean_exception_xci ${repo_dir}/src/pl/${module}/semi_top/*/*.xci
    set clean_exception_prj ${repo_dir}/src/pl/${module}/semi_top/*/*.prj
    foreach clean_file ${clean_list} {
        if {{$clean_file} ne {$clean_exception_xci}} and {{$clean_file} ne {$clean_exception_prj}} {
            file delete -nocomplain $clean_file
        }
    }
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
invalid bareword "clean_file"
in expression "clean_file ne clean_exception_xci";
should be "$clean_file" or "{clean_file}" or "clean_file(...)" or ...
    (parsing expression "clean_file ne clean_ex...")
    invoked from within
"if {clean_file ne clean_exception_xci} and {clean_file ne clean_exception_prj} {
        file delete -nocomplain clean_file
    }"
    ("foreach" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"foreach clean_file ${clean_list} {
    if {clean_file ne clean_exception_xci} and {clean_file ne clean_exception_prj} {
        file delete -nocomplain clea..."
    (procedure "add_module" line 37)
    invoked from within
```

Could anyone please give me a hint of what might be going on? (I figure the code would only deal with files, not directories. Someting probably have to be added to deal with directories as well...)

Thanks! /Teddy

Comment: Why `and` used here ? Do you intend to use logical AND ? Then it should be `&&`.

Comment: I wish the code prettifier did not insist on applying C-style comments to every language.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line:

```
if {{$clean_file} ne {$clean_exception_xci}} and {{$clean_file} ne {$clean_exception_prj}} {
```

You need to use `string match` to determine if a string matches a glob pattern, not the `ne` operator (which does negated exact string comparison). You also need to use the right number of braces; you've got too many! In addition, `and` is not an operator in Tcl at all.

I think this is the correct way to do it:

```
if {![string match $clean_exception_xci $clean_file] && ![string match $clean_exception_prj $clean_file]} {
```

However, I'd be happier with using shorter lines and `continue`; I think that generates cleaner code.

```
foreach file $clean_list {
    if {[string match $clean_exception_xci $file]} {
        continue
    }
    if {[string match $clean_exception_prj $file]} {
        continue
    }
    file delete -nocomplain $file
}
```

It's longer, but much clearer (well, to me) that we're applying two filtering operations.

Comment: Hello. THanks for the help. I think the deleting part works ok now, however there is another problem I just realized.
The "clean_exception_xci" (and "_prj") are not just one file, it is in fact a list of files. I changed the set-row to:
    
`set clean_exception_xci [glob -nocomplain ${repo_dir}/src/pl/${module}/ip_catalog/*/*.xci]`

   `set clean_exception_prj [glob -nocomplain ${repo_dir}/src/pl/${module}/ip_catalog/*/*.prj]`

Would you solve this using nested foreach loops when doing the string matching? (Sorry about the bad formatting...)

Comment: Ah. If you've got a list of actual files then you can use the `ni` operator.

Answer (score 0):

final code:

```
set clean_list [glob -nocomplain ${repo_dir}/src/pl/${module}/ip_catalog/*/*]
set clean_exception_xci_list [glob -nocomplain ${repo_dir}/src/pl/${module}/ip_catalog/*/*.xci]
set clean_exception_prj_list [glob -nocomplain ${repo_dir}/src/pl/${module}/ip_catalog/*/*.prj]

foreach file $clean_list {
    set _break 0

    foreach except_file_xci $clean_exception_xci_list {
        if {[string match $except_file_xci $file]} {
        incr _break
        break
        }
    }

    foreach except_file_prj $clean_exception_prj_list {
        if {[string match $except_file_prj $file]} {
        incr _break
        break
        }
    }
    if {$_break > 0} continue
    file delete -force $file
}
```

Works like a charm. I guess using the "ni" command would work as well. instead of the inner foreach-loop, one should be able to use something like:

```
if {[string match $file ni $clean_exception_xci_list]} {
    continue
}
```

etc. but I am happy :) Thanks!